# Javascript form validation not working due to typos

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

### HTML

```
<form name="registerForm" action="/user/register.cgi" method="post" onsubmit="validateRegisterForm()">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="password" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Register Details"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

## Javascript

```
function validateRegisterForm(){
var fname=document["registerForm"]["firstname"].value;
var lname=document["registerForm"]["lastname"].value;
var email=document["registerForm"]["email"].value;
var atpos=email.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=email.lastIndexOf(".");
var pass=document["registerForm"]["password"].value;
var passlen = pass.length;
var confpass=document["registerForm"]["cofirmPassword"].value;

if (fname==null || fname=="")
  {
  alert("Please enter a First Name!");
  return false;
  }
else if (lname==null || lname=="")
  {
  alert("Please enter a Last Name!");
  return false;
  }
else if (email==null || email=="")
  {
  alert("Please enter a email!");
  return false;
  }
else if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
  {
  alert("Please enter a valid email address!");
  return false;
  }
else if (pass==null || pass=="")
  {
  alert("Please enter a Password!");
  return false;
  }
else if (6<=passlen<=15)
  {
  alert("Password needs to be to have a lenght of 6-15!");
  return false;
  }
else if (pass!=confpass)
  {
  alert("Passwords do not match!");
  return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: `onsubmit="ValidateRegisterForm()"` is enough. No need of `return` there

Comment: this is a horrible validation,use a validation framework.

Comment: i got it from here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp what frame work would you recommend?

Comment: fleunt validation or data annotations if asp, data annotations is loaded by default in your project, then all you have to do is form.Validate()

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was a simple typo and adds no value to the site. The title makes it show up in search results to all users and will only slow them down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in your code

`cofirmPassword` should be `confirmPassword`

should be

```
     var confpass=document["registerForm"]["confirmPassword"].value;
```

Instead of

```
      var confpass=document["registerForm"]["cofirmPassword"].value;
```

**UPDATE**

Your mistakes are

`x.length` should be `email.length`

`(6<=passlen<=15)` should be `(passlen < 6 || passlen > 15)`

Your updated working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DQ4rQ/3/)

Comment: thanks it appears I made a few typos when copying it over however it is all the fields that don't work not just that one. thanks for finding it though.

Comment: @user3258090, earlier there were some errors, but after your edited there is only one :).

Comment: thanks this might have fixed it but im really not sure what iv done to make it work

Comment: Have you run DEMO at jsfiddle in above my answer, your code is working there.

Comment: can you please tell me `x.length` means?

Comment: should be getting the length of the string

Comment: thanks this was what the problem was. i also talked to someone online who decided that i should change the validate email function aswell

Answer (score 0):

Today, in the times of HTML5, it's preferable to use the new validation mechanisms built into the browsers. A general approach is to define a constraint checking function per property (preferably in the model class in a JavaScript-based MVC app, like `User.checkEmail`) and assign it via HTML5's `setCustomValidity` function as an event listener for `input` events to the input field elements, so the user gets immediate validation feedback on user input, like in

```
emailInpEl.addEventListener("input", function () { 
  emailInpEl.setCustomValidity( User.checkEmail( emailInpEl.value).message);
});
```

So, whenever the string represented by the expression `User.checkEmail(emailInpEl.value).message` is empty, everything is fine. Otherwise, if it represents an error message, the browser indicates the constraint violation to the user by marking the form field concerned (typicallly with a red border) and by displaying the error message.

You can read more on using the programmatic HTNL5 validation techniques in [this tutorial](https://oxygen.informatik.tu-cottbus.de/IT/JsFrontendApp/simple-tutorial.html).

Answer (score -1):

your JavaScript Code is wrong try this one

```
function validateRegisterForm(){
  var fname=document.getElementByName["registerForm"][0].value;
  var lname=document.getElementByName["registerForm"][0].value;
  var email=document.getElementByName["registerForm"][0].value;
  var atpos=email.indexOf("@");
  var dotpos=email.lastIndexOf(".");
  var pass=document.getElementByName["registerForm"][0].value;
  var passlen = pass.length;
  var confpass=document.getElementByName["registerForm"][0].value;

 if (fname==null || fname=="")
 {
   alert("Please enter a First Name!");
   return false;
 }
  else if (lname==null || lname=="")
  {
    alert("Please enter a Last Name!");
    return false;
   }
  else if (email==null || email=="")
  { 
    alert("Please enter a email!");
    return false;
  }
  else if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
  {  
   alert("Please enter a valid email address!");
   return false;
  }
  else if (pass==null || pass=="")
  {
   alert("Please enter a Password!");
   return false;
  }
  else if (6<=passlen<=15)
  {
    alert("Password needs to be to have a lenght of 6-15!");
    return false;
  }
   else if (pass!=confpass)
   {
     alert("Passwords do not match!");
     return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: when you set the variables at the start how does it know which item in the form it is?